# When using \input{document_with_tikz.tex} the paths inside document_with_tikz.tex getting wrong

Tags: tikz-pgf, standalone, paths, structure

I have some main document and want to insert another .tex file which contains a tikz-picture (standalone documentclass).
In my project I have a folder for some shared preambles like commands of usepackages etc.
Compiling just my document with the tikzpicture works correct as the path shows the correct "way":

```
%%File with the picture: standalone_cube.tex%%
\input{../../../_shared_preambles/tikz_packages.tex}
begin
<<code for picture>>
end
```

But when using \input from the main-file to include this picture:

```
\input{_images/tikz/standalone/standalone_cube.tex}
```

I think latex just replace the "insert" with the text standing in my standalone_cube.tex. But when this get an 1:1 copy the path I use inside this is getting wrong I guess and so my document wont compile.

Is there any kind of solution that latex track the movement to the file I want to insert and so the relative path still work? I guess I could just place all files in one folder so do't have to go up- or downwards in folders, but then the structure gets messy.

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: in your title you use `\insert` I assume you did not use `\insert` in your document, please edit to clarify

Comment: Why not to work with the precompiled pdf output given by tikz code in standalone class, then import to the main document as an image within figure environment using graphicx package like in this post [Scaling different components of tikzpicture together.](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/435629/154390)

Comment: Also try `\input{./_images/tikz/standalone/standalone_cube.tex}`