Adding pdfs from custom directory inserts only one page
When I put the "ToBeInserted.pdf" file in my latex project folder (XeLaTex, TexLive 2024), it inserts all the pages. However, if I put into any other directory it inserts only one page! Why could it be happening?
First case (working fine)
\includepdf[pages=-]{ToBeInserted.pdf}

Second case (inserts only the first page of the pdf)
\includepdf[pages=-]{\detokenize{/Users/someone/Mobile Documents/com~apple~CloudDocs/ToBeInserted.pdf}}

Secondly, I saw somewhere that, tlmgr can add the directory permanently for any latex projects to use the files from that directory, but it isn't working (no error when the following is run, but not inserting any files upon compilation):
tlmgr conf auxtrees add /Users/someone/Mobile Documents/com~apple~CloudDocs/ToBeInserted.pdf

Expected setting and outcome: I put all the pdfs to be attached in a iCloud folder named /Users/someone/Mobile Documents/com~apple~CloudDocs/, in my system (in different paths/folders other than the previous one) where many LaTeX projects are there. Then somehow let know TexShop (or the complier) that when I add something like this \includepdf[pages=-]{ToBeInserted.pdf} in a .tex file, it has to look for the ToBeInserted.pdf automatically in that folder without me explicitly taking the hassle of adding the whole path (with special characters) everytime. Hoping this explanation helps. Thanks,
Related:

How to include PDF file in LaTex Doc from folder location?
Let tex search a file inside a folder?


Try a directory which is located on your machine. Could folders can sometimes cause problems.

Why detokenize ?

The tlmgr auxtree is for specifying a texmf directory not individual files and you would need to quote the space in the path, but you shouldn't need that here I think

@samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz, the directory is in my machine, in the same storage where TexLive 2024 is installed. Sorry, don't get "Could folders can sometimes cause problems."

@DavidCarlisle, because I don't know the details but took the cue from this answer: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/446558

Mac treats folders like /Users/someone/Mobile Documents/com~apple~CloudDocs/ differently. Try with a folder called test on your desktop to see if that's the problem. Another possible problem might be if your user name contains special characters.

I also tried, but this but the complier still cannot look into the intended folder or find the files within tlmgr conf auxtrees add "/Users/someone/Mobile Documents/com~apple~CloudDocs"

Does it work if you use \includepdf[pages=-]{/Users/someone/Desktop/test/ToBeInserted.pdf} and place the pdf there?

@samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz, that works but not when I try to add the path with tlmgr and then only invoke this \includepdf[pages=-]{ToBeInserted.pdf}, complaining •/test.tex:528: Package pdfpages Error: Cannot find file 'ToBeInserted.pdf'

@massisenergy Try https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/79060/36296 with a folder which is NOT a cloud folder (and doesn't have any special characters)

This issue is due to the primitive \detokenize that changes catcodes. Thereupon the check of the filename extension doesn't work correctly and pdfpages erroneously assumes that your file is not a PDF and therefore cannot have more than one page. Like a PNG for instance. And thus pdfpages includes only the first page. (Note that this check is only relevant for XeLaTeX.)
I will fix this issue. So far either omit \detokenize (Why do you need it at all?) or add the following code to your document:
\usepackage{pdfpages}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\makeatletter
\edef\AM@pdf@ext{pdf}
\patchcmd\AM@getpagecount{%
 \edef\type@ext{%
    \noexpand\lowercase{%
      \noexpand\def\noexpand\type@ext{.\filename@ext}}}%
  \type@ext}{%
   \begingroup\edef\x{%
    \lowercase{\endgroup
      \def\noexpand\type@ext{\expandafter\scantokens\expandafter{\filename@ext\noexpand}}}}
  \x}{}{}
\makeatother


this isn't a super concise one-liner I was expecting for, but definitely works! I'll wait for some more days if anybody comes up with other solutions.

without \detokenize, it fails to read the path as it involves spaces and special characters, e.g. com~apple~CloudDocs Do you have any alternate solutions for that?

Spaces work fine for me without using \detokenize. However, concerning the tilde character, I do need \detokenize as well. But this is exactly what my solution provides: Compatibility with \detokenize.
