# How to use fit tikzpicture in a LaTeX file

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-pic

I use `tkiz` to draw a picture in LaTeX. It works with me with `\documentclass[border=5pt,tikz]{standalone}`. However, when I try to use the same code in my original LaTeX file `\documentclass[english]{IEEEtran}`, it does not fit in the paper. How can I edit the following code to use it in my LaTeX file?

```
\documentclass[border=5pt,tikz]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows,positioning}
\newcommand{\parallelsum}{\mathbin{\|}}
\newcommand{\point}{\textbullet\hspace{1em}}
\everymath{\displaystyle}

        \begin{document}

    \begin{tikzpicture}[every node/.style={inner sep=6pt,draw,anchor=east},>=triangle 60]
        \node[xshift=1cm] (a) {\textcolor{red}{$V_1$ generate a temporary key pairs} $[Pk^{1}_{v_{1}}, Pr^{1}_{v_{1}}]$};
            \draw[->,cyan] ([yshift=.3cm,xshift=2cm]a.east) --+ (5,0) node[black,midway,above=.1cm] {$Pk^{1}_{v_{1}}$};
            \draw[<-,cyan] ([yshift=-.3cm,xshift=2cm]a.east) --+ (5,0) node[black,midway,below=.1cm] {$\mathcal{T}_{1}= {M_{1} || Sh_{R_{1}}}$};
        \node[right=9.5 of a,yellow!70!black,fill=yellow] (b) {\Huge\textcolor{white}{$R_1$}};
        \node[right=1 of b] {
            \begin{tabular}{l}
            \point    Generate: $M_1 = \{Pk^{1}_{v_{1}},   \textcolor{red}{\mathrm{tag}_{\mathrm{he}_1,R_1}}\}$ \\
            \point    Calculate: $\mathrm{S}_{R_1}(M_1)$
            \end{tabular}
        };
        \begin{scope}[yshift=-3cm]

            \node (a) {
                \begin{tabular}{p{7cm}}

                \textcolor{blue}{\point Run the PoW algorithm to get $S_{\mathcal{T}_{1}}$} \\
                \point $L_{R_{1}}=({\mathcal{T}_{1}||S_{\mathcal{T}_{1}}|| Pk^{2}_{v_{1}} ) || \sigma_{Pr^{1}_{v_{1}}}(\mathcal{T}_{1}||S_{\mathcal{T}_{1}}|| Pk^{2}_{v_{1}}}) $
                \end{tabular}
            };

            \draw[->,cyan] ([yshift=.3cm,xshift=1cm]a.east) --+ (5,0) node[black,midway,above=.1cm] { $\mathrm{L}_{R_1}$};
            \draw[<-,cyan] ([yshift=-.1cm,xshift=1cm]a.east) --+ (5.8,0) node[text width=5.8cm,black,midway,below=.1cm] { $\mathcal{T}_{2}= \{\mathcal{T}_{1} ||Sh_{R_{2}}(M_{1}) || M_{2} || Sh_{R_{2}}(M_{2} )\}  $};
            \node[right=8.5 of a,yellow!70!black,fill=yellow] (b) {\Huge\textcolor{white}{$R_2$}};
            \node[right=1 of b] (c) {
                \begin{tabular}{l}
                    \point Verify $\mathrm{L}_{R_1}$ and Shares. \\
                    \point Checks if: $(t_r-t_1)<\mathrm{Certain\ target\ value}$ \\

                    \point $M_{2}=\{Pk^{2}_{v_{1}} || (t_{1}, Tag_{R_{1}}) || (t_{2}, Tag_{R_{2}})\}$   \\
                    \point Calculate: $Sh_{R_{3}}(M_{2})$ \\

                    \point Calculate: $Sh_{R_{3}}(M_{3})$\\
                \end{tabular}
            };
        \end{scope}
        \draw[o-o,dashed] ([yshift=1.5cm]a.west) -- ([yshift=1.5cm]c.east);

    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Well, the perhaps simplest option might be to include the pdf of the picture in your document. If this is not an option for you, you may tell us if you set any length parameters in your document different from the defaults of your class since this may help us judging whether or not the picture will fit. Or is your question how to redesign your picture in such a way that it becomes narrower?

Comment: @marmot I am using the standard  IEEEtran conferences format: \documentclass[english]{IEEEtran}. I just need to the figure to fit in my paper not include it as a picture. I try many solutions but I got many errors.

Comment: I guess it will be very hard to fix this. You have many large explicit dimensions, explicit shifts and so on. The IMHO most promising way would be a more or less complete redesign.

Comment: @marmot could you help me with that. As I am very new to tkiz. Just fix me a part of the code so I can learn how to fix the remaining by myself.

Comment: This post may help you [Scaling different components of tikzpicture together.](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/435629/154390)

Comment: Scaling your tikzpicture to \columnwidth renders it unreadable.  You might try a two column version using figure*.  BTW, there is no difference between scaling a tikzpicture and a PDF containing a tikzpicture.  Both are done using the graphicx package.

Comment: Since you have some responses below that seem to answer your question, please consider marking one of them as ‘Accepted’ by clicking on the tickmark below their vote count (see [How do you accept an answer?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1852)). This shows which answer helped you most, and it assigns reputation points to the author of the answer (and to you!). It's part of [this site's idea to identify good questions and answers through upvotes and acceptance of answers](http://tex.stackexchange.com/about).

Comment: If your problem is solved, the normal procedure is to accept a solution: https://tex.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers

Answer (score 6):

Is this what you are looking for?

```
\documentclass[conference]{IEEEtran}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows,positioning}
\newcommand{\parallelsum}{\mathbin{\|}}
\newcommand{\point}{\textbullet\hspace{1em}}
\everymath{\displaystyle}
\usepackage{lipsum}% MWE only

\begin{document}
\begin{figure*}[tp]
\resizebox{\textwidth}{!}{%
    \begin{tikzpicture}[every node/.style={inner sep=6pt,draw,anchor=east},>=triangle 60]
        \node[xshift=1cm] (a) {\textcolor{red}{$V_1$ generate a temporary key pairs} $[Pk^{1}_{v_{1}}, Pr^{1}_{v_{1}}]$};
            \draw[->,cyan] ([yshift=.3cm,xshift=2cm]a.east) --+ (5,0) node[black,midway,above=.1cm] {$Pk^{1}_{v_{1}}$};
            \draw[<-,cyan] ([yshift=-.3cm,xshift=2cm]a.east) --+ (5,0) node[black,midway,below=.1cm] {$\mathcal{T}_{1}= {M_{1} || Sh_{R_{1}}}$};
        \node[right=9.5 of a,yellow!70!black,fill=yellow] (b) {\Huge\textcolor{white}{$R_1$}};
        \node[right=1 of b] {
            \begin{tabular}{l}
            \point  Generate: $M_1 = \{Pk^{1}_{v_{1}},   \textcolor{red}{\mathrm{tag}_{\mathrm{he}_1,R_1}}\}$ \\
            \point  Calculate: $\mathrm{S}_{R_1}(M_1)$
            \end{tabular}
        };
        \begin{scope}[yshift=-3cm]


            \node (a) {
                \begin{tabular}{p{7cm}}

                \textcolor{blue}{\point Run the PoW algorithm to get $S_{\mathcal{T}_{1}}$} \\
                \point $L_{R_{1}}=({\mathcal{T}_{1}||S_{\mathcal{T}_{1}}|| Pk^{2}_{v_{1}} ) || \sigma_{Pr^{1}_{v_{1}}}(\mathcal{T}_{1}||S_{\mathcal{T}_{1}}|| Pk^{2}_{v_{1}}}) $
                \end{tabular}

            };




            \draw[->,cyan] ([yshift=.3cm,xshift=1cm]a.east) --+ (5,0) node[black,midway,above=.1cm] { $\mathrm{L}_{R_1}$};
            \draw[<-,cyan] ([yshift=-.1cm,xshift=1cm]a.east) --+ (5.8,0) node[text width=5.8cm,black,midway,below=.1cm] { $\mathcal{T}_{2}= \{\mathcal{T}_{1} ||Sh_{R_{2}}(M_{1}) || M_{2} || Sh_{R_{2}}(M_{2} )\}  $};
            \node[right=8.5 of a,yellow!70!black,fill=yellow] (b) {\Huge\textcolor{white}{$R_2$}};
            \node[right=1 of b] (c) {
                \begin{tabular}{l}
                    \point Verify $\mathrm{L}_{R_1}$ and Shares. \\
                    \point Checks if: $(t_r-t_1)<\mathrm{Certain\ target\ value}$ \\

                    \point $M_{2}=\{Pk^{2}_{v_{1}} || (t_{1}, Tag_{R_{1}}) || (t_{2}, Tag_{R_{2}})\}$   \\
                    \point Calculate: $Sh_{R_{3}}(M_{2})$ \\

                    \point Calculate: $Sh_{R_{3}}(M_{3})$\\
                \end{tabular}
            };
        \end{scope}
        \draw[o-o,dashed] ([yshift=1.5cm]a.west) -- ([yshift=1.5cm]c.east);

    \end{tikzpicture}
}
\caption{Sort of obligatory}
\end{figure*}

\lipsum[1-16]
\end{document}
```

[image: demo]

Comment: I try to run your code on my latex but it is talking too much time with no output.

Answer (score 6):

I tried to redesign your picture and apologize in advance for all the mistakes I made, e.g. by breaking your formulae incorrectly.

```
\documentclass[english]{IEEEtran}
\usepackage{tikz,tikzpagenodes} % tikzpagenodes only for illustration
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta,positioning}
\newcommand{\parallelsum}{\mathbin{\|}}
\everymath{\displaystyle}
\begin{document}
  \begin{tikzpicture}[every node/.style={inner sep=2pt,draw,anchor=east},
  >={Triangle},R-block/.style={text width=0.35\textwidth},
  L-block/.style={text width=0.25\textwidth}]
  % start with the R nodes
    \node[yellow!70!black,fill=yellow,text=white,font=\Huge] (b){$R_1$};
    \node[left=4cm of b,L-block] (a) {\textcolor{red}{$V_1$ generate a temporary key pairs} $[Pk^{1}_{v_{1}}, Pr^{1}_{v_{1}}]$};
    \draw[->,cyan] ([yshift=.3cm]a.east) -- ([yshift=.3cm]a.east -|b.west) 
        node[black,midway,above=.1cm] {$Pk^{1}_{v_{1}}$};
    \draw[<-,cyan] ([yshift=-.3cm]a.east) -- ([yshift=-.3cm]a.east -|b.west) 
        node[black,midway,below=.1cm] {$\mathcal{T}_{1}= {M_{1} || Sh_{R_{1}}}$};
    \node[right=2mm of b,R-block] (c) {\vspace{-1ex}\begin{itemize}
     \item   Generate: $M_1 = \{Pk^{1}_{v_{1}},   \textcolor{red}{\mathrm{tag}_{\mathrm{he}_1,R_1}}\}$ \\
     \item  Calculate: $\mathrm{S}_{R_1}(M_1)$
    \end{itemize}
     };
    \node[below=2.5cm of b,text=white,font=\Huge,fill=yellow] (b') {$R_2$};
    \node[left=4cm of b',L-block] (a') {\vspace{-1ex}\begin{itemize}
      \item Run the PoW algorithm to get $S_{\mathcal{T}_{1}}$
      \item $L_{R_{1}}=(\mathcal{T}_{1}||S_{\mathcal{T}_{1}}||Pk^{2}_{v_{1}} )$
      $ ||\sigma_{Pr^{1}_{v_{1}}}(\mathcal{T}_{1}||S_{\mathcal{T}_{1}}|| Pk^{2}_{v_{1}})$
      \end{itemize}
      };
     \draw[->,cyan] ([yshift=.3cm]a'.east) -- ([yshift=.3cm]a'.east -|b'.west)  
     node[black,midway,above=.1cm] { $\mathrm{L}_{R_1}$};
     \draw[<-,cyan] ([yshift=-.3cm]a'.east) -- ([yshift=-.3cm]a'.east -|b'.west)
     node[text width=3cm,black,midway,below=.1cm,align=center] 
     { $\mathcal{T}_{2}= \{\mathcal{T}_{1} |$ $|Sh_{R_{2}}(M_{1}) |$ $| M_{2} || Sh_{R_{2}}(M_{2} )\}  $};

     \node[right=2mm of b',R-block] (c') {\vspace{-1ex}\begin{itemize}
       \item Verify $\mathrm{L}_{R_1}$ and Shares. 
       \item Checks if: $(t_r-t_1)<\mathrm{Certain\ target\ value}$ 
       \item $M_{2}=\{Pk^{2}_{v_{1}} || (t_{1}, Tag_{R_{1}}) || (t_{2}, Tag_{R_{2}})\}$   
       \item Calculate: $Sh_{R_{3}}(M_{2})$ 
       \item Calculate: $Sh_{R_{3}}(M_{3})$
      \end{itemize}
     };
     \path (c'.north east) -- (c.south east) coordinate[midway] (R);
    \draw[{Circle[open]}-{Circle[open]},dashed] (R) -- (R-|a.west);
  \end{tikzpicture}
% only for illustation
\begin{tikzpicture}[overlay,remember picture] 
\draw[red,dashed] (current page text area.south west) rectangle 
(current page text area.north east);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your help. I try to copy the code to my TeXstudio program But it keeps trying to run and it is taking so much time without any response.

Comment: @Mohamed I have no idea what happens on your machine. All I know that this code runs without problems on my updated TeXLive 2018 distribution. The only thing that I do not get from this contribution is `IEEEtran.cls`. Where did you get your version from? You seem to also have a problem with John Kormylo's code. Perhaps this suggests that you update your TeX installation.

Comment: it works with me. Thank you very much. Is there is any way to resize the text inside the boxes? As it seems the text is not in a straight line.

Comment: If this question worked for you, you should accept the answer with the green check, if you have additional questions you can ask them in another question centered on those issues or on other improvements.

Comment: @Mohamed I think all texts are on straight lines. You can resize texts as is done in the yellow boxes, e.g. with `font=\large`. You can also say `scale=0.8`, say, but I would not do either since then the texts are different from what is in the main text.